# How do I create a Single JAR for source code spanning multiple projects in Eclipse and another JAR with just the dependencies using Maven

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin, apache-storm

I am trying to create a single JAR out of multiple projects in eclipse using Maven. My requirement is to make two JARs, 1. single JAR with source code for all projects 2. single JAR with all the dependencies without the source code.

I am deploying this to a Storm Cluster for which I need different JARs since JAR with dependencies is very fat. Thank you!

Comment: An usual jar-with-dependencies generated by the assembly plugin with the aprropriate option doesn't contain sources.

Comment: ok, I actually need a single JAR which spans across multiple projects. I am not sure weather this can be done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697683/maven-multi-module-project-assembly-into-single-jar