# Build multi-module project into a single jar with Maven2

Tags: java, maven

I have read this:
[maven: multi-module project assembly into single jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697683/maven-multi-module-project-assembly-into-single-jar)

For the accepted answer of that question, my maven version is 2.2.1 and `shade` need maven 3.

My parent pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>x-all</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <modules>
        <module>x-framework</module>
        <module>x-adaptor</module>
        <module>x-plugin</module>
        <module>x-utils</module>
        <module>x-offline</module>
        <module>x-protocols</module>
    </modules>
...
```

I just want to build a `x-all-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` that includes

1. every sub-module class
2. every sub-module dependency class (need resolve dependency conflict automatically)
3. some resource file(in `x-all/src/main/resources`)

How do I build that?

Comment: @khmarbaise I and my teammates try to build it for at least 3 hours... Tried dozens of solutions..

Comment: What's the reason you're using maven 2.2? Can't you upgrade to maven3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another module, for example, call it `x-package`. let `x-package` depends every module in that project. And we just run `mvn package` with a simple `assembly plugin` configuration(`jar-with-dependence`), we will get the wanted jar in `x-package`'s target directory.